# Typed Racket Polymorphic Function cannot be applied

Tags: types, scheme, racket, typed-racket

```
> (map (λ: ([x : (Pairof Symbol Number)]) (cdr x)) (list (cons (quote a) 0.3) (cons (quote b) 0.2) (cons (quote c) 0.5)))
- : (Listof Number) [generalized from (Pairof Number (Listof Number))]
'(0.3 0.2 0.5)
> (sum '(0.3 0.2 0.5))
- : Real
1.0
> (sum (map (λ: ([x : (Pairof Symbol Number)]) (cdr x)) (list (cons (quote a) 0.3) (cons  (quote b) 0.2) (cons (quote c) 0.5))))
. Type Checker: Polymorphic function map could not be applied to arguments:
Types: (a -> c) (Pairof a (Listof a)) -> (Pairof c (Listof c))
   (a b ... b -> c) (Listof a) (Listof b) ... b -> (Listof c)
Arguments: ((Pairof Symbol Number) -> Number : ((! False @ (cdr) 0) | (False @ (cdr) 0)) (cdr 0)) (List (Pairof 'a Positive-Flonum) (Pairof 'b Positive-Flonum) (Pairof 'c Positive-Flonum))
Expected result: (Listof Real)
 in: (map (λ: ((x : (Pairof Symbol Number))) (cdr x)) (list (cons (quote a) 0.3) (cons (quote b) 0.2) (cons (quote c) 0.5)))
```

Why do the first and second expressions, `> (map ...` and `> sum ...` work as I expect, but trying to combine them throws a type error?

```
> sum
- : ((Listof Real) -> Real)
#<procedure:sum>
```

I don't quite understand why `map` is returning a `(Listof Number) [generalized from (Pairof Number (Listof Number))]` instead just `(Listof Number)`, based on what I thought `map` does.

Comment: You should post the definition of `sum`

Comment: Just want to point out that I did not define `sum` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that `sum` expects `(Listof Real)`  but  `map` was returning `(Listof Number)`. The solution is to use `(apply + (map ...))` instead of `(sum (map ...))`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is one of the following:

1. you are declaring the parameter `x` to be a `Number`
2. You are declaring `sum` to work with `Real`s

Somewhere in the (Typed) Racket docs the type tree is explained. The problem with your code is that `Real` is a subtype of `Number`. So while your `map` produces a list of `Number`s the sum function will only accept a more specific type which (thankfully) produces an error.

You can fix it by either letting sum handle any kind of `Numbers` (assuming you're using + that should be safe to do) or you specifically declare `x` to be a `Real` (which might not always be correct, but in this limited example works fine).

Comment: 1. s/he is defining `x` as `Pairof ...`, the `λ` returns `Number` though. 2. s/he is not defining `sum`. `sum` is from `math/base`.